# What's the best practice to put node.js config files in s3, instead of same server

Tags: node.js

Don't ask me why, we want to run node.js in server1, but want its config files in server2 (say in s3).
What's the recommended way to do this ?

i could read config file directly when starting my node app, but want to see practical ways.

Comment: When somebody says "don't ask me why" all I can help but wonder is "why"

Comment: because it's out of my control, i cannot give you a good reason if you asks.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by signing a URL with a long expiration date.  That way, I could safely update configs in the bucket, and the servers would get the configuration when they started up.

Unfortunately, the ability to sign URLs for longer than 7 days is removed with the V4 signatures.  V2 signatures stop working on June 24th of this year.

However, you could have your own server (or Lambda function) receive the request for config and redirect them to a signed bucket URL.  Just be very careful to authenticate the config request securely.